# Because it does not make the dynamic change, v-mask, vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I have the following input

```
<input
  type="text"
  :disabled="disabledMoney"
  v-model="packageForm.crime.forgeryCrimeSelected"
  v-mask="{alias: 'currency', digits:0, min:minMoney, max:maxMoney}"
  autofocus
/>
```

to which I assign the property `max:maxMoney` of `data ();`
This input is shown based on a radio button, so when selecting the radio button the input appears and with its correct max value, but if I try to change the max value in a method, the change no longer applies
in the method I just do

```
change(){
  this.maxMoney = 6000 // Assigning new max
}
```

But it does not apply and stays with its initial value

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use a computed value. This will re calculate everytime there is a change in state with the values involved.

Here is some reading from the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Hey based on your comment, I would do something like this:

```
<input
  type="text"
  :disabled="disabledMoney"
  v-model="packageForm.crime.forgeryCrimeSelected"
  v-mask="{alias: 'currency', digits:0, min:minMoney, max:maxMoneyComp }"
  autofocus
/>
```

```
computed: { maxMoneyComp(){ return packageForm.crime.forgeryCrimeSelected == 10000 ? 10000:25000; } }
```

Comment: instead of using this.maxMoney. use the return value from the function?

Comment: Is what he did
`computed:{
  maxMoneyComp(){
     return  this.maxMoney = packageForm.crime.forgeryCrimeSelected == 10000 ? 10000:25000;
  }
}`
and I use maxMoneyComp in v-mask but not function